# ACR122 NFC-Reader/-Writer Java Application (Interface implementation)

Tags: java, nfc, acr122

currently I am struggling with an interface between the  [ACR122 NFC Reader](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/) and java. What I am trying to achieve is to read a NFC-Tag and get the read value into a java variable. Sounds simpler than it is (for me).

What I do know by know are the bytes I have to send in order to read and write properly. So what I now need to know is how do I communicate with the device itself so i can send those commands (initialize, read/write, close connection)?

The manufacturer adds a interface written in C (or C++?). Unfortunately I only know Java so I would need a library I could use and some examples (and maybe some explanations). If someone would happen to know how to achieve my goal and going to explain to me how the process generally works, I would be very happy.

Some additional informations:

- Operating System the programm should work on (Windows 7 64x)
- The most recent JDK
- The transfer and the stored data on the NFC-Tag doesn't have to be secure

If any information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask for it. I am glad for every bit that helps.

Comment: Would help if you added how the Reader is connected to the PC. Via Network or USB or ... Mail Pidgeon? If there is a C- "Interface", have you considered native calls to that?

Comment: I just saw on the site you linked, there is a "Downloads" Section. In there, there is a "Android-EVK" - whatever that is - but Android is as close to Java as you can get regarding those downloads. If this "EVK" contains a Javaish connector, you can probably "have yourself inspired" by it.

Comment: The ACR122U is connected through PC/SC. You can use javax.smartcardio to access it.